# Unable to Boot Server in normal Mode

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Server 2008 Enterprise R2 SP1 Server. The server went into a hung state. On rebooting , The server boots up to the windows screen and blacks out, Tried the following options on the server to bring it back online however unsuccessful.

2. Safe Mode
3. Safe mode with networking
4. Last Known good configuration
5. Tried Booting the server from CD for repair option, However once the cd is in, it does not provide the option to repair. A little bit of search concluded thatStart Repair is not available in Windows Server 2008
6. Power Drain
7. System file check (SFC.exe)

Only thing that works is

1. Safe Mode with Command Prompt.

I disabled the non microsoft services like symantec and also the SQL services while in Safe mode with command prompt and tried to restart it in normal mode, However ,It again boots up to the Windows Screen and blacks out.
Also checked the system and application logs in eventviewer, However no direct indications of what went wrong

Any clues on what to do further to bring it up normally other than the one that we tried?

Comment: @ Ward, HopelessN00b, Scott Pack, mdpc, Adrian - Respect your decision to downvote and close out this question. I now seek your guidance to avoid doing the same thing again. I did go through the FAQ's & i really could not get a clear picture as to why this is not a good fit for the Q& A format. I did see the examples & I do not see a major difference...The answer that I gave was based on Fact which worked for me and may help others, additionally I sought guidance from others to see if this can be done in some other way when the registry becomes corrupt..How can this be done in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution worked to bring it online

1. Booted the server into recovery console with OS media
2. Took the backup of the System and Software registry hive from the below folder to D Drive

   > C:\Windows\System32\Config
3. Renamed the System and Software hive from the Config folder
4. Copied the System and Software hive from the Regback folder to Config folder

   > C:\Windows\System32\Config\Regback
5. Booted the server without media CD.
6. Server boot into normal mode without any issue